# Calculating relative root systems

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, root-systems

Let $\mathbf{G}$ be a connected semisimple algebraic group defined over a field $k$.  Let $T$ be a maximal torus of $\mathbf{G}$ defined over $k$, and let $S \subset T$ be a maximal $k$-split torus.  Let $\Phi = \Phi(T,\mathbf{G})$ be the absolute root system of $\mathbf{G}$, and let $\Phi_{\text{rel}} = \Phi(S,\mathbf{G})$ be the relative root system.

Let $T^{\ast}$ and $S^{\ast}$ be the groups of characters of $S$ and $T$.  The restriction map $T^{\ast} \rightarrow S^{\ast}$ restricts to a surjection
$\Phi \sqcup \{0\} \rightarrow \Phi_{\text{rel}} \sqcup \{0\}$.
We can view
$\Phi$ and $\Phi_{\text{rel}}$
as subsets of
$T^{\ast} \otimes \mathbb{R}$ and $S^{\ast} \otimes \mathbb{R}$.  The root system structures on $\Phi$ and $\Phi_{\text{rel}}$ come from Euclidean inner products on these Euclidean spaces that are invariant under the actions of the Weyl group and the relative Weyl group.

Let's say that I am working with $k$-forms of a semisimple algebraic group that I understand well.  I can therefore compute the Euclidean inner product on $T^{\ast} \otimes \mathbb{R}$ as well as the kernel $K$ of the restriction map $T^{\ast} \rightarrow S^{\ast}$.  This is enough to determine $\Phi_{\text{rel}}$ as a subset of $S^{\ast} \otimes \mathbb{R}$.  But what I don't know how to do is compute the Euclidean inner product on $S^{\ast} \otimes \mathbb{R}$, which is the last thing I need to actually determine the root system $\Phi_{\text{rel}}$.

Another way of saying what I want to be able to compute is the inner product between elements of $\Phi_{\text{rel}}$.  My guess is that what you do is as follows.  Consider elements $r,r' \in \Phi_{\text{rel}}$.  There are then unique lifts $\tilde{r},\tilde{r}' \in T^{\ast} \otimes \mathbb{R}$ that are orthogonal to the kernel $K$, and I suspect that the inner product of $r$ and $r'$ equals the inner product of $\tilde{r}$ and $\tilde{r}'$.

**Question**: Is my guess correct, and is there a source that spells it out like this?

I apologize for two things:

1. I have never really worked with algebraic groups over fields that are not algebraically closed before, so since I am self-taught in that area I might be writing things in non-standard ways.
2. I know that instead of $\Phi_{\text{rel}}$ I should write $\Phi$ with the field $k$ as a left subscript.  I know several ways to do this in LaTeX, but they all seem to break the in-line LaTeX processor used by MathOverflow.

Comment: @LSpice: Sigh.  I promise I'm not this sloppy in real life...

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453077/calculating-relative-root-systems#comment1171980_453077), well understood.  Nothing ever goes so wrong as when you try to do something you can do easily, but with people watching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $W(G, S)(k) = (N_G(S)/C_G(S))(k) = N_G(S)(k)/C_G(S)(k)$ is finite, there is what Borel, in [Linear algebraic groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-0941-6), §14.7, calls an admissible scalar product on $S^* \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb R$, obtained simply by averaging any random scalar (i.e., inner) product over its $W(G, S)(k)$-orbit.  Then his Theorem 21.6 says that any such choice of admissible scalar product makes $\Phi_\text{rel}$ a root system, with Weyl group $W(G, S)(k)$.  Per your [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453077/calculating-relative-root-systems/453080#comment1171972_453080) and my [response](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453077/calculating-relative-root-systems/453080#comment1171974_453080), if you wish to do this without knowing $W(G, S)(k)$ directly, then Borel’s Corollary 21.4 says that you can just work with the subgroup $W(G, T, S)(k^\text{sep})$ of $W(G, T)(k^\text{sep})$ that stabilises $S$.

You can typeset a left subscript in a fairly naïve way, using $_k\Phi$ `_k\Phi`.  This does not work well if it's not at the beginning of a formula, as in $\Phi(G, S) = _k\Phi$ `\Phi(G, S) = _k\Phi`.  I prefer to shut this off with surrounding braces, like $\Phi(G, S) = {_k\Phi}$ `\Phi(G, S) = {_k\Phi}`, but many people just use an extra atom, like $\Phi(G, S) = {}_k\Phi$ `\Phi(G, S) = {}_k\Phi`.  (A full solution might be something like `\newcommand\lsub[2]{\vphantom{#2}_{#1}#2}`, and then $\newcommand\lsub[2]{\vphantom{#2}_{#1}#2}\lsub k\Phi$ `\lsub k\Phi`.  I suspect that packages like [`leftidx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/leftidx) do something like that, but cleverer.)

Comment: That's right, but in the situation I am in I don't actually know the relative Weyl group yet (just the absolute one, and as far as I can tell there is no simple relationship between them).  I'm hoping to figure out the relative Weyl group after determining the relative root system.

Comment: (ps: I tried to typeset the relative root system like you suggest when I originally wrote the question, but each time though it gave the right output the first few occurrences the tex started rendering gibberish about half-way through.)

Comment: @Ann, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453077/calculating-relative-root-systems/453080#comment1171972_453080), Borel's Corollary 21.4 says that, if $W(G, T, S)(k^\text{sep})$ is the subgroup of $W(G, T)(k^\text{sep})$ that stabilises $S$, then $W(G, S)(k)$ is the “restriction of $W(G, T, S)(k^\text{sep})$ to $S$”, i.e., the Weyl group is the group of orthogonal transformations of $S^* \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb R$ coming from elements of $W(G, T, S)(k^\text{sep})$.  So you can just average over $W(G, T, S)(k^\text{sep})$ instead.

Comment: @Ann, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453077/calculating-relative-root-systems/453080#comment1171973_453080), if you could reproduce the error—say, in the [formatting sandbox](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/55/formatting-sandbox)—and post a link, I would be happy to see if I could figure out what happened.

Comment: Ah, Borel's Corollary 21.4 is exactly what I was looking for, and I think it implies that my guess as to the answer is correct.  Thanks for the help, and I apologize for asking such an elementary question!

Comment: @Ann, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453077/calculating-relative-root-systems/453080#comment1171976_453080), no need to apologise; relative-root-system questions can be surprisingly subtle.  Even in the quasisplit case, [Adler and Lansky - Root data with group actions](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-981-13-6628-4_3), Theorem 7, shows that the construction of coroots can have some wrinkles.